# Kafka offset management with Spark structured streaming 2.2 batch API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Just want to know if checkpointing of Kafka offsets will work with Spark structured stream (2.2) batch API or do we need to manage the offsets?

Comment: Which batch API are you referring to? Structured Streaming exposes no such API.

Comment: spark.read instead of spark.readStream

Comment: There is a kind of "unsafe" solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77987406/1220930

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the batch DataFrame reader (e.g. `spark.read.format("kafka")`) and NOT the stream reader (e.g. `spark.readStream.format("kafka")`) then no, there is no built-in offset management. Since it's a batch API, you would normally specify the offsets yourself as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries). For streaming then Spark can do the offset management for you since it will read multiple ranges of batches as it's continuously processing.

Comment: Thanks Silvio. That was my guess but still wasn't very sure as both streaming and batch apis are built over the same framework and it should be easy to provide checkpointing for batch apis too.