# How does Structured Streaming ensure exactly-once writing semantics for file sinks?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing a storage writer for spark structured streaming which will partition the given dataframe and write to a different blob store account. The spark documentation says the it ensures `exactly once` semantics for file sinks but also says that the exactly once semantics are only possible if the source is re-playable and the sink is idempotent.

1. Is the blob store an idempotent sink if I write in parquet format?
2. Also how will the behavior change if I am doing `streamingDF.writestream.foreachbatch(...writing the DF here...).start()`? Will it still guarantee exactly once semantics?

Possible duplicate : [How to get Kafka offsets for structured query for manual and reliable offset management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153105/how-to-get-kafka-offsets-for-structured-query-for-manual-and-reliable-offset-man)

Update#1 : Something like -

```
output
      .writeStream
      .foreachBatch((df: DataFrame, _: Long) => {
        path = storagePaths(r.nextInt(3))

        df.persist()
        df.write.parquet(path)
        df.unpersist()
      })
```

Comment: What's "blob store" in your question? S3?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Azure blob storage

Answer (score 5):

### Micro-Batch Stream Processing

I assume that the question is about Micro-Batch Stream Processing (not Continuous Stream Processing).

Exactly once semantics are guaranteed based on available and committed offsets internal registries (for the current stream execution, aka `runId`) as well as regular checkpoints (to persist processing state across restarts).

> exactly once semantics are only possible if the source is re-playable and the sink is idempotent.

It is possible that whatever has already been processed but not recorded properly internally (see below) can be re-processed:

- That means that all streaming sources in a streaming query should be **re-playable** to allow for polling for data that has once been requested.
- That also means that the sink should be **idempotent** so the data that has been processed successfully and added to the sink may be added again because a failure happened just before Structured Streaming managed to record the data (offsets) as successfully processed (in the checkpoint)

### Internals

Before the available data (by offset) of any of the streaming source or reader is processed, `MicroBatchExecution` commits the offsets to Write-Ahead Log (WAL) and prints out the following INFO message to the logs:

> Committed offsets for batch [currentBatchId]. Metadata [offsetSeqMetadata]

A streaming query (a micro-batch) is executed only when there is new data available (based on offsets) or the last execution requires another micro-batch for state management.

In **addBatch** phase, `MicroBatchExecution` requests the one and only `Sink` or `StreamWriteSupport` to process the available data.

Once a micro-batch finishes successfully the `MicroBatchExecution` commits the available offsets to commits checkpoint and the offsets are considered processed already.

`MicroBatchExecution` prints out the following DEBUG message to the logs:

> Completed batch [currentBatchId]

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate on how ` Continuous Stream Processing` is different then?

Comment: @Gelerion Not prepared at the moment. In summary: there are no micro-batches so checkpointing is committing offsets at regular intervals, but again I've not much knowledge to answer continuous case. Sorry.

Comment: @JacekLaskowskim the basic goal to use `forEachBatch()` is to write every batch to randomly selected storage account from a pool of storage accounts. See Update#1

Comment: @HareshKhanna Writing to randomly-selected storage accounts changes nothing actually as the exactly-once guarantees are per micro-batch.

Answer (score 1):

When you use foreachBatch, spark guarantee only that foreachBatch will call only one time. But if you will have exception during execution foreachBatch, spark will try to call it again for same batch. In this case we can have duplication if we store to multiple storages and have exception during storing.
So you can manually handle exception during storing for avoid duplication.

In my practice I created custom sink if need to store to multiple storage and use datasource api v2 which support commit.