# Does Structured streaming handles the data loss without any extra config/coding?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

For example, i'm using Kafka as a source using Structured Streaming.

**Update:** As per the documentation, one cannot set the `auto.offset.reset` param https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations Is there any specific reason why Structured Streaming does not leverage the `auto.offset.reset` value as `None`, i hope that could resolve the data loss by default.

Then where does Structured streaming stores the consumed offsets?

Since the `startingOffsets` default value is `latest` what happens if i have to deploy new code or re-start the application because of some failures? in this case if the value is `latest` then there will be data loss.

Do i still have to do something like `checkpointing` and `write-ahead-logs` etc to handle the failure?

As per this link, even after check-pointing and write-ahead-logs there will be problems in recovery semantics. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovery-semantics-after-changes-in-a-streaming-query

Can we deploy the new changes with same check-point location? when we tried with old Direct approach, it does not allow you to deploy the new changes with same check-point location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Structured Streaming ensure exactly-once writing semantics for file sinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704664/how-does-structured-streaming-ensure-exactly-once-writing-semantics-for-file-sin)